# Forwarded connection refused by server: Administratively prohibited. Using both @IP and PermitOpen

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, security, configuration, forwarding

[This Machine is 192.168.80.125]

Normal SSH Rules to allow all basic access:

```
AllowUsers                  user1
PubkeyAuthentication        yes
PasswordAuthentication      no
AllowTcpForwarding          yes
UsePAM                      no
```

Match Group test

```
AllowUsers                  user2@IP1 user2@IP2 user2@IP3 user2@IP4
PubkeyAuthentication        yes
PasswordAuthentication      yes
AllowTcpForwarding          yes
    PermitOpen              192.168.80.100:80
    PermitOpen              192.168.80.125:443
AllowAgentForwarding        no
```

When I am connecting to the sshd from IP1 as user2 I can connect, I open my tunnel with PuTTY:

Local S:IP1:8080
Remote D:192.168.80.100:80

Local Src :IP1:8443
Remote Dest :192.168.80.125:443

I open my browser and browse to localhost:8080 I get connection reset.
I open my browser and browse to localhost:8443 I get connection reset.

I check SSH Log:

```
192.168.80.125 authlog: Received request to connect to host 192.168.80.100 port 80, but the request was denied.
192.168.80.125 authlog: Received request to connect to host 192.168.80.125 port 443, but the request was denied.]

Event Log: Opening connection to 192.168.80.125:443 for forwarding from [::1]:3585
Outgoing packet : (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN)
Incoming packet : (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_FAILURE)
Event Log: Forwarded connection refused by server: Administratively prohibited [open failed]

OpenSSH_7.5p1 Ubuntu-10ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

I can successfully reach the resources at 192.168.80.125:80 / 192.168.80.125:443 when using SSH as user1 and pubkey/etc and TCP Forward works correctly to anything.

I had the PermitOpen setup first and this worked. I then added the user2@ restrictions and this is what broke this.

Is there a better way to do this? I want to ensure user2 can only tunnel to the specified resources and can only login from specified IP.

I also noticed that when I login as user2 and switch to user1 the forwarding rules are still based off user2.

Answer (score 5):

Well this is embarrassing. Apparently I had the incorrect syntax for PermitOpen.

I found that if you list multiple lines of PermitOpen only the first line is actually active.

The correct syntax:

`PermitOpen <IP>:<port> <IP>:<port> <IP>:<port>` ... And so on, on one line.